# Implement a condition which is based on calls from different external IBActions?

Tags: swift

I have these two `IBActions` in **WorkoutsController.swift**.

```
@IBAction func startWalkingButton() {

    print("Walking start button pressed")
    presentControllerWithName("Dashboard", context: sessionContext)

    wSM!.startWorkout()
}


@IBAction func startCyclingButton() {
    print("Cycling start button pressed")
    presentControllerWithName("Dashboard", context: sessionContext)

    wSM!.startWorkout()
}
```

They are calling the `startWorkout()` function in **WorkoutSessionManager.swift**

```
func startWorkout() {
    self.healthStore.startWorkoutSession(self.workoutSession)

    if ... {
    print("startWorkout() called from startWalkingButton")
    } else if ... {        
    print("startWorkout() called from startCyclingButton")
     }
    }
```

How do I create a condition to print out different `print` statements depending on which `button` function called the method? Should I use an if statement or switch statement?

I know there is already a print statement for the separate `IBActions` but I want to know if it's possible to do it in the reverse for redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add one `Bool` parameter with your method `startWorkout`

```
func startWorkout(isFromWalking: Bool) {
    if (isFromWalking) {
        print("startWorkout() called from startWalkingButton")
    }
    else {
        print("startWorkout() called from startCyclingButton")
    }
}
```

Now call this function from `startWalkingButton` method with passing `true`

```
startWorkout(true)
```

and from `startCyclingButton` method with passing `false`

```
startWorkout(false)
```

**Edit:**

You haven't told that you have multiple option, then best option is to used enum in this case, create one enum like this and use that with the method

```
enum Workout  {
   case Walking
   case Cycling
   //Add case that you have
}

Now change the function like this 

func startWorkout(workout: Workout) {
    switch(workout) {
    case .Walking :
        print("Walking")
    case .Cycling:
        print("Cycling")
    }
}
```

And call the function like this

```
self.startWorkout(.Walking)
self.startWorkout(.Cycling)
```

Comment: Hey that worked! So dang easy! Amaze balls! Thanks. Btw, I actually have a 3rd button called startRunningButton I didn't include for brevity. How would I add that 3rd button into the mix? Would I have to create a second argument called isFromRunning? How would I deal with `startWorkout(false/true)`?

Comment: @tymac try a enum instead of bool.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add some sort of 'sender' parameter to your `startWorkout()` method.

Example:

```
// Hold a reference to your buttons, connected from IB
@IBOutlet var startWalkingButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var startCyclingButton: UIButton!

// here are your .TouchUpInside actions
// UIControl action methods receive the sender of the event as the first parameter (sender)

@IBAction func startWalkingButtonTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    ...
    startWorkout(sender)
}

@IBAction func startCyclingButtonTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    ...
    startWorkout(sender)
}

func startWorkout(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.healthStore.startWorkoutSession(self.workoutSession)
    switch sender {
    case startWalkingButton:
        print("startWorkout() called from startWalkingButton")
        break

    case startCyclingButton:
        print("startWorkout() called from startCyclingButton")
        break

    default: ()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: These are different swift files i.e. external calls. That's why when I start typing `startWalkingButton` there is no auto-complete. I know how to use sender in the same class but these are different classes.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should probably use a block here. `startWorkout` method should accept an optional block. This approach avoids passing arguments and also avoids having `if` and `case` statements.

```
class Walking {
    let workout = Workout()

    func startWalkingButton() {
        print("startWalkingButton")
        workout.startWorkout() {
            print("Walking Over")
        }
    }
}

class Cycling {
    let workout = Workout()

    func startCyclingButton() {
        print("startCyclingButton")
        workout.startWorkout() {
            print("Cycling Over")
        }
    }
}

class Workout {
    func startWorkout( afterWorkout: () -> Void ){
        print("startWorkout")
        afterWorkout()
    }
}

let w = Walking()
w.startWalkingButton()
```

Comment: Ok Felix thank you.  Could you please provide a code example based on my code? Much appreciated.

Comment: @tymac I updated my answer with an example. Sorry about not providing that before.

Comment: This won't work because it doesn't recognize any of my properties since they're out of scope. Property in question is in its own context etc. It's a  class file with custom class, protocol and context.

Comment: Thank for your help. I just couldn't use your example with my particular project. It would get too complex. Cheers.